# When the Processor code of Java Custom Annotation is called? (runtime retention)

Tags: java, annotations, processor

I know that **Custom Java Annotations** need a semi interface declaration with `@interface` and a **processor** code (in some text it's called the consumer code) which defines the actual business logic behind the annotation. So far so clear, but my question is that, **where/when exactly the processor code is called and by whom**? I mean, does Java compiler generate the code which invokes all the annotation processors, for example, at class loading time? or the programmer themselves decide when to call their processor codes for their custom annotations?
for example, `@GetMapping("/users")` on some method, tells the servlet API to map the requests with /users in their request path, should be delivered to this method. so it has some processor behind the scene which should be called **to store this Mapping configuration somewhere**, but when and who calls that processor? I guess my question makes sense only on the annotations with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`. Thanks

Comment: There is no requirement to have annotation processors for each custom annotation. You can simply read them via Reflection, for example. And a servlet can not run on its own. To run a servlet, you need an implementation of the very framework that provided the definition of the annotation that has a meaning to the servlet framework. So it should be clear which software processes those annotations.

Comment: @Holger I didn't mean that we have to write a processor for servlet annotations or such, I know that Spring Web has already written the processor for the annotation. my problem is that when is that processor called? and by whom?

Comment: Maybe we have to clarify first, what you understand by the name "processor".

Answer (score 0):

An [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) runs at compile time.  When invoking `javac`, the user passes the `-processor` command-line option, and then `javac` invokes the processor.  An annotation processor can issue errors, create files (including files of Java code), and even modify existing code.  In addition to the Oracle documentation linked above, you might want to see a tutorial, such as [Baeldung's](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder).

Some frameworks directly interpret annotations, so you don't need to write your own annotation processor.

To affect run-time behavior, your code can reflectively read annotations; in this case no annotation processor is run at compile time.

Comment: do you mean that the compiler do not just compile the processor(generate byte code)? and it also runs it as well? that something that really amazes me :)

Comment: Also thanks for the Baelgung's article, however that article dives into a @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) example, however my question is chiefly on @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) cases.

Comment: You have edited your question to say it's about runtime retention, but that does not change the question or the answer.  The term "annotation processing" refers to compile-time processing.  Compile-time annotation processing is applicable no matter what the retention of the annotation is.

Comment: Okay, let's go by an example, @GetMapping should save a mapping between some text in http request path and a method in our controller right? because according to your comment it is run at compile time, it has to generate some external file for the mappings, right? and at runtime, the Spring Boot Web will read the file to redirect the requests to their intended controller methods. but the question is, when is the first time that the mentioned external file is read? is it on first http request? or there's some kind of initialization at some point in the start up of our Spring Boot Application?

Answer (score 0):

An `Annotation` as the name suggests, is additional information (or behavior). By default, this information is not processed or used to alter any behavior. There has to be some entity to process the annotation.

The retention policy tells the Java compiler about the scope of the annotation. That is, whether the extra information is needed to be processed at runtime or compile-time.

For compile-time processing, the `annotation processors` are hooked into the compilation process using the `-processor` flag. For run-time processing, reflection (such as [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getDeclaredAnnotations())) is used to access the additional information.

> @GetMapping("/users") on some method, tells the servlet API to map the requests with /users in their request path,

Just the presence of the annotation does not result in this behavior. The spring framework (simplifying a lot) -

- installs itself as the servlet endpoint for `/*`. See [FrameworkServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html)
- enumerates the methods annotated with `GetMapping` using reflection
- uses the annotated information to populate the mapping of URLs to methods.
- while handling the requests, uses the mapping to route to the intended method.

One easy trick to understand the flow (yes, Java is too magicy sometimes) is to install breakpoints and look at the callstack.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, the question is not about functionality of the processor or the annotation, rather it is only about when and by whom, the processor is called? example answer: it is run by Java Runtime and at class loading time. or: it is called by the library itself and at an arbitrary time.